# Why is this question with 2700+ upvotes locked?

Tags: discussion, locked-posts, locked-votes

I tried to upvote [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) and got the error message:

> Question is locked...

So why is this question with more than 2700 upvotes locked? And why is it possible to lock a **JavaScript** question by a user with just 56 JavaScript tag points?

Comment: The lock banner pretty much explains it: _"This question's answers are a collaborative effort: if you see something that can be improved, just edit the answer to improve it! No additional answers can be added here"_

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ My Question is about Upvotes not Answers. I can't upvote it.

Comment: Yeah, overlooked that detail a bit. It's like @Pekka explains. He's able to do it because of having mod privileges.

Comment: It is just a side-effect of the question getting locked.  A moderator steps in when it gets to be too much of a hassle to maintain the Q+A.  It already has too many answers now, you can't see the large number of truly useless answers that had to be deleted.  A question like this where just about everybody knows an answer keeps mods endlessly busy when users flag bad posts.  Locking puts a stop to that.  Fwiw, examples of such bad posts are: "There's a plugin in the jquery gallery"  and "Chuck Noris can parse the Query String. Without even looking".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Animuson is a moderator. (In the meantime, he has even become a Stack Overflow employee.)

That question is a textbook "list of things" and "resource request" type question that is off topic on Stack Overflow, regardless of how many upvotes it has.

It does not take domain specific knowledge to recognize that this question is not on topic on Stack Overflow.

It is kept around solely for historical purposes, because it has so many useful contributions.

Comment: /OT are we going back to _normal state_ slowly??

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Comment: You say it is off topic, but according to the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/901115/revisions) it was never closed. Also, it was left open from the review queue [two](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/2806274) [times](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/2629852)

Comment: @Pekka웃 [See here please](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/31886949#31886949)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ only a short reprise, I'm sure. Tomorrow, we'll be back to Documentation questions!

Comment: @user000001 yeah, on a closer look, it is not as clear-cut a case as I first figured it to be.

Comment: @Pekka웃 You mean it's just a short _let us breath up_? :( ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes. Documentation will rule all the things for at least a fortnight more.

Comment: @Pekka웃 For me that's a good sign that it's incomplete and broken.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ it currently certainly has huge flaws. Let's see whether they get fixed.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Hugest flaws I've ever seen with a SO public beta proposal. ATM they should troll it back all over and have another iteration of the development process IMHO: All that rep should be bound to _nirvana_ ...